# What does << do in Python?

Tags: python

I solved a problem on Project Euler but it took about 4 minutes to run, which is above the recommended time, so I was looking through the different solutions in the forum.  One of them included the symbol `<<` in a list comprehension.  This is what it looked like

```
blist.extend([(i << 1) + 3 for i in range(num) if alist.get(i)])
```

I can't find anywhere what exactly this `<<` symbol does. Can someone help me?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [bit shift operator (Python docs)](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations), and is common among many programming languages, such as C, Java, PHP, etc.  According to the Python docs:

> They shift the first argument to the
>   left or right by the number of bits
>   given by the second argument.
>
> A right shift by n bits is defined as
>   division by pow(2, n). A left shift by
>   n bits is defined as multiplication
>   with pow(2, n). Negative shift counts
>   raise a `ValueError` exception.

So in your specific case, `i << 1` means left shift by 1 bit, which is equivalent to multiplying by 2^1, or just 2.

Comment: so then if it is i>>1 would it be mod(i,2) or would it move to the right past a decimal?

Comment: Right shift is division by 2^n, or in the case you cited, just 2.  Off the top of my head, I think it's just integer division too, so I don't think you'll get decimal values...

Comment: right that is what i meant, i don't know why i said mod. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary bitwise shift operator.

```
x << n
x shifted left by n bits

x >> n
x shifted right by n bits
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the left-shift operator. It shifts all of the bits in i to the left by 1 step, effectively multiplying i by 2.

http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations